# Control-click objective c Xcode function - helper class

Tags: objective-c, class, controls, helper

On Ray Wenderlich site I saw this:

> So control-click on GDataXML, choose Add\New File, choose iOS\Cocoa Touch Class\Objective-C class, and click Next. Name the class GDataXMLElement-Extras.m, make sure “Also create GDataXMLElement-Extras.h” is checked, and click Finish.

And he gets this:

```
@implementation GDataXMLElement(Extras)

- (GDataXMLElement *)elementForChild:(NSString *)childName {
NSArray *children = [self elementsForName:childName];            
if (children.count > 0) {
    GDataXMLElement *childElement = (GDataXMLElement *) [children objectAtIndex:0];
    return childElement;
} else return nil;
}

- (NSString *)valueForChild:(NSString *)childName {    
return [[self elementForChild:childName] stringValue];    
}
```

And

```
@interface GDataXMLElement (Extras)

- (GDataXMLElement *)elementForChild:(NSString *)childName;
- (NSString *)valueForChild:(NSString *)childName;

@end
```

Its funny, but I just cant get the same new classes with that "(Extras)". Any help ?? Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `Objective-C category` instead of an `Objective-C class`

Comment: I don't think this one is created like that. GDataXMLElement-Extras.h would be GDataXMLElement+Extras.h if created with category but its not. Might get same result and functioning at the end if created with category but just interested in how he got that this way. Tnx anyway.

Comment: In the tutorial he just creates a class and replaces the contents with that code. The tutorial misses the Objective-C convention of naming categories with a `+` symbol between the name of the class and the name of the category. I'd stick to convention and not just copy the example code found here.

Comment: For clarification - the tutorial is creating a `category` - just in an awkward way and not named correctly.